# Use LINQ to group multiple columns & split data into several lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Recently I have a task which need to do as following description, my question is that is LINQ capable to do it?

Say I have a set of data, each consists of three columns: `a(int),b(int),c(int)`

What I want to do is to group these data by `a and b`, and for each distinct pair `(a,b)`, store their corresponding `c` into separate list.

For example: If I have a set of data(a,b,c) `{(1,3,5), (2,4,6), (1,3,7), (2,4,8)}`,

I want to split the data into two separate list, each contains `c`'s value:

List 1 (a=1,b=3) : [5,7]

List 2 (a=2,b=4) : [6,8]

What I have tried is to group / order by the data by `(a,b)`, and got a sorted list of data, I can of course use any loop to iterate the set of data and split them into several list, just wondering if there is a more beautiful solution, like using a single LINQ query?

Any suggetion is pleased! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.a, x.b })
                 .Select(g => Tuple.Create
                 (
                     new List<int> { g.Key.a, g.Key.b }, 
                     new List<int>(g.Select(x => x.c))
                 )).ToList();
```

Here's the query expression equivalent:

```
var result = (from x in data
             group x by new { x.a, x.b } into g
             select Tuple.Create(
                 new List<int> { g.Key.a, g.Key.b }, 
                 new List<int>(g.Select(x => x.c)))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!  Just want to ask, how can I do this in LINQ to entities? i.e. from s in data...

Comment: You are amazing, you got 666 rating now :)